# Find attribute of object == some value, using the find method

Tags: c++, class, debugging, object

I have a `Holiday` class

```
class Holiday
{
    public:


    private:
        string id;
        string destinationCode;
        string destinationName;

};
```

I am trying to use the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) method to find if any of the `Holiday` objects in a vector of `Holiday` contains the attribute : string ID  which equals to `H001`

This is what i have tried

```
    vector<Holiday>::iterator h1;
    vector<Holiday>::iterator h2;
    vector<Holiday>::iterator h3;


    h1 = this->holidayPackages.begin();
    h2 = this->holidayPackages.end();

    h3=find(h1,h2,"H001");
```

I get a compiler error

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'Holiday'

**How do i find the attribute of a Holiday object using the find method ??**

EDIT: I am looking for a `NON C++11 answer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` template needs the `operator==` to be defined. So, try this:

```
bool Holiday::operator==(const string& other) const {
  return id == other;
}
```

Also don't forget to declare this operator in the class:

```
class Holiday
{
    public:
        bool operator==(const string& other) const;

    private:
        string id;
        string destinationCode;
        string destinationName;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have no operator == and not utilizing C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Holiday
{
    public:
    const std::string& get_id() const { return id; }

    private:
    std::string id;
    std::string destinationCode;
    std::string destinationName;

};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Holiday> holidays;

    struct Predicate {
        bool operator () (const Holiday& holiday) {
            return holiday.get_id() == "H001";
        }
    };

    std::find_if(holidays.begin(), holidays.end(), Predicate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `std::find` to search in a list of items of different type, but you can use `std::find_if`, like this:

```
h3 = find_if(h1, h2, [] (const Holiday& h) { return h.id == "H001"; } );
```

Note: the above uses the lambda syntax, which is not available prior to C++11. If your compiler is not C++11-compatible, you would need to provide a "regular" function for comparing the `id` with the target value.

Answer (score 0):

Your iterators are for `Holiday` instances, but you are trying to compare a `Holiday` with a `const char*` when calling `find`. How is the compiler to know that it should compare the string with `id` rather than with `destinationCode` or `destionationName`

If you're got access to C++11 you can use a lambda:

```
auto it=std::find_if(h1, h2, [](const Holiday &h){return h.id=="H001";});
```

Answer (score 0):

find function needs a == operator to check is something in the vector equal to the third argument so define a == operator in your class like this:

```
bool operator==(const string& other) const {
  return id == other;
}
```